# How to increase width or height of JasperViewer (Hard coded)?

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

This is my code

```
static Connection connHealthInfoSystem = DBConnection.conn("health_info_system");
public static void printDisplayable(String reportPath, Map parameter) {
    JasperDesign jd;
    try {
        jd = JRXmlLoader.load(reportPath);
        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, parameter, connHealthInfoSystem);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JasperPrinting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Based on the current code that I have, how can I increase the size of the width of my report when it pops up?

Comment: You can find the answer here: [How to customize a JasperViewer](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/530551/how-customize-jasperviewer), [Setting Viewer zoom/width](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/534373/setting-viewer-zoomwidth), [How to set the size of the JasperViewer?](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/535133/how-set-size-jasperviewer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `jd.setPageWidth(999);` before `JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);`

Comment: As far as I can understand OP wants to increase the size of the frame that "pops up" when `JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);` is invoked, not the size of the actual report, this they probably would specify in the jrxml.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the static method `JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);`, since this way you don't have control of `JasperViewer` object instead instance your own `JasperViewer`

```
JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(jp, false);
```

[`JasperViewer`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/view/JasperViewer.html) extends [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) so you can set size, location as for any `JFrame`, just remember to set it visibile when your done.

**Example**

```
JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(jp, false);
viewer.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //You can set location
viewer.setSize(new Dimension(1000,600)); //You can set size or you set preferredSize and the pack it.
viewer.setVisible(true); //When you are ready, you set the frame to be visibile
```

Comment: Oh thanks for a great advice but i always put param.clear() (my param is the object for the report) on every reporting.

Answer (score -1):

I have never worked with this but if u look at code only thing which is hardcoded is `"health_info_system"` so i suppose you can use some resource folder and fetch it mby.. or just make it a constant.

```
private static final String HEALTH_INFO_SYSTEM_DB = "health_info_system";
```

Comment: that code is intended only for opening up connection and i am looking forward to adjusting the width of the report which is not relatable to the connection.

Comment: @KebabKrabby How is your answer correlates with question?